# Add the difference of two pandas column values to a new row if the difference is greater than a column value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

'''
This is a sample of data I have
'''

```
PERIOD GROUP USER_COUNT REGION
50    A     55            AX
25    A     20            AX
30    B     33            BY
40    C     10            CZ
```

Expected Output

```
PERIOD GROUP USER_COUNT REGION
50    A        50         AX
50    A         5         AX
25    A        20         AX
30    B        30         BY
30    B        3          BY
40    C        10         CZ
```

Comment: Can we know the reason behind doing this @sk01?

Comment: @vishnu.. I am working on a data set where I am supposed to identify the difference between 2 columns and assign the difference to new column like above.. this is a real time use case I have started working where I am checking the num of subscribers for a paricular period under a particular group and if there are hierarchy levels to achieve this.. like.. first at subgroup, then group.. then cluster and so on.. I have grouped the original dataset category wise till i achieved any count exceeding a period.. then split  count if it is greater again to two categories and make suggestions..

Comment: Whatever you just said @sk01 doesn't make sense to me. I just wanted to know why do we need a new row?

Comment: @Vishnudev.. I know it really sounds so.. after this particular step.. I need to group the remaining values at the next heirachy level and so on to see how many total groups/ combinations can be formed.. to explain it's a little hard and it's being messy as well to keep re doing a similar operation.. but i couldn't think of an alternative way at the moment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#get difference of columns
s = df['USER_COUNT'].sub(df['PERIOD']) 
#mask for positive subtract values
m = s > 0

#subtract of original data ony matched rows of column VAL2
df1 = df.assign(USER_COUNT = lambda x: x['USER_COUNT'].sub(s[m], fill_value=0))
#overwrite matched rows
df2 = df[m].assign(USER_COUNT = s[m])

#join together and sorting by only stable sorting - mergesort
df3 = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
         .sort_index(kind='mergesort')
         .reset_index(drop=True)
         .astype(df.dtypes))
print (df3)
   PERIOD GROUP  USER_COUNT REGION
0      50     A          50     AX
1      50     A           5     AX
2      25     A          20     AX
3      30     B          30     BY
4      30     B           3     BY
5      40     C          10     CZ
```

Comment: It worked but then at certain places the val1 is getting replaced with the difference

Comment: @sk01 - Is possible be more specific? I  have no real data, working only for sample data.

Comment: the difference between val1 and val2 (say for the 1st row is 5, now 5 is being added under val1 in the consecutive row..)

Comment: @sk01 - Is possible change data sample for see it? Because now working like you need

Comment: sorry didn't get u.,. do u want me to edit my question?

Comment: @sk01 - exactly, for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: tried editing the question.. but I have similar data only with a change in names

Comment: @sk01 - One idea - Is possible use `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` before my solution for default index values?